# How do I make a text box in ActionScript 3?

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm trying to learn ActionScript 3, but right now I'm hung up on getting a basic interface set up. I've found out that `newTextField` will make one, but I don't know how to put it where I want.

I've checked out some source code for other projects using the same IDE (Adobe Flash CS6) and they seem to have access to a textbox symbol. So how do I make one of the textbox symbols with the IDE, or using some code?

Answer (score 1):

```
var tf:TextField = new TextField;
tf.text = "Hello World!";
addChild(tf);
```

These will create black text reading 'Hello World!'.

Find out more about text fields here: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/TextField.html